# ERROR: pq: invalid input syntax for type json

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have an orders table with a column named `description` which stores additional information such as promotional code and a few other things in a JSON format.

I want to query all the orders which are made using a particular promotional code say `WELCOME100` and wrote a query as shown below.

```
select o.id
from orders o
where o.description is not null and (o.description::jsonb) ->> 'promotionCode' = 'WELCOME100'
```

This is throwing the below error

> ERROR: pq: invalid input syntax for type json

Can someone help me with what went wrong in the above query?

Comment: Can you share some data from the description column?

Comment: Apparently your `description` column contains values that are not valid JSON. Why isnt' that column defined as `jsonb` to begin with? The you wouldn't have that problem now